# AngularJS count html attributes occurrence in each controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I hava a SPA AngularJS app with 2 views (2 controllers A and B). I need to count the number of occurrences of attribute x in each controller.

I count doing `document.querySelectorAll('[x]')` in both controllers.

For instance:

View 1 (controller A) has 1 occurrence of attribute "x".
View 2 (controller B) has 2 occurrences of attribute "x".

So when I go from View 1 -> View 2 the count will be "erroneously" 3 occurrences of x in controller B. I assume it has to do with being a SPA and the html is already loaded in memory or something like that?

Comment: approach is wrong to count elements in the DOM, use array lengths from data model. If you need to share data across controllers, use a service. If needed have a service method that returns the count also

Comment: @charlietfl hmm can you give a simple example?

Comment: create a simple plunker demo that shows what you are trying to do rather than me have to work up example from scratch that may not even fit what you are doing. Doesn't even need to have routing if you just separate 2 controller scopes in same view

Comment: simple example  http://plnkr.co/edit/qdvwrDPcyf4ij7VCbwRC?p=preview

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your example but I don't understand how that relates to my scenario? I want to count html attributes as I wrote in the question.

Comment: where's the example? What determines those attributes? Likely the data model no?

Comment: @PeterWarbo, to avoid trying to solve an XY problem, please explain what you are actually trying to accomplish? What is this attribute `x`? What sets it, and when. What charlietfl was trying to say was that with Angular one does not reason in terms of DOM elements, but rather in terms of a model. So, in a well-designed Angular app, the model drives the DOM, and so instead of finding occurrences of an attribute `x`, you count the data that led to that attribute to be generated.

Comment: @charlietfl of course, so silly of me :\ I completely forgot that it's the data model that determines how many attributes should be displayed... thanks for your effort!

Comment: takes a bit to get away from thinking of the DOM first ... once you think data first it becomes a lot easier